# Opencart admin login is showing HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: opencart

This is the url http://www.iwantthis.co.in/opencart/admin/

```
Here is the errorlog file
```

```html
[16-Nov-2019 14:50:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(../vqmod/vqmod.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wp88umzgp8jr/public_html/opencart/admin/index.php on line 17
[16-Nov-2019 14:50:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../vqmod/vqmod.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/wp88umzgp8jr/public_html/opencart/admin/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: This HTTP ERROR 500 not contain any info about your issue. You should check on your server error logs  and post it here. Maybe then someone can help. If you can not access this logs, please ask you server provider to check it and send to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the VQMOD folder has been deleted / moved. If you weren't using VQMOD you can remove the offending code from both index.php files:

To test this, comment out these lines:
/index.php:

```
// VirtualQMOD
//require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
//VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
//require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));
```

/admin/index.php:

```
//VirtualQMOD
//require_once('../vqmod/vqmod.php');
//VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
//require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));
```

The bigger question is why is the VQMOD folder is missing from the original path?

Answer (score 0):

VQMOD folder is missing in your website. download VQMOD extension and upload it to your website by FTP

http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/administration/vqmod/

Comment: i uploaded vqmod now i am getting this error

PHP Fatal error:  -----
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/wp88umzgp8jr/public_html/opencart/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 341

Comment: @chaitanya edit php.ini file and increase memory_limit to 128M. `memory_limit = 128M;`

Comment: i tried both memory_limit = 128M; and memory_limit = 512M;
still the same error

Comment: Rename `php.ini` to `.user.ini` and check